# std::max behaves unexpected with uniform initialization and constexpr int

Tags: c++, max, std, constexpr

I am experimenting with std::max. I am tring to pass integers constexpr with uniform initialization (curly braces), to compare them to floating-point variables.

Experiment a): Call std::max() with double/int mixed

```
    double a = 3.0;
    int b = 5;
    auto res = std::max(a, b);
```

Does not compile. Clang reports `error: no matching function for call to 'max'`. This is of course OK.

Experiment b): Use curly braces + constexpr int for non-anrrowing conversion

```
    double a = 3.0;
    constexpr int b = 5;
    auto res = std::max(a, {b});
```

Compiles and works as expected: returns a double with value 5.0.

Experiment c): Same as b) but swap arguments of std::max.

```
    double a = 3.0;
    constexpr int b = 5;
    auto res = std::max({b}, a);
```

Does not compile both under gcc and clang. Why?

Clang reports `error: called object type 'double' is not a function or function pointer`.

Comment: `std::max<double>(a, b)` should work. `max(a, b)` doesn't compile because the compiler cannot deduce the template parameter - one argument says it's `int`, the other says it's `double`. Putting `{b}` in curly braces makes it non-deduced context, removing the ambiguity; the template parameter is now successfully deduced from `a` alone.

Comment: Your last example [works](https://godbolt.org/z/zPCCSx) for me.

Comment: @cigien You are not including `<algorithm>` which is required to make `std::max` available.

Comment: @walnut Oh, wow, UB strikes again. Nice catch, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists an overload of `std::max` that looks like this (from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)):

```
template< class T, class Compare >
constexpr T max( std::initializer_list<T> ilist, Compare comp );
```

This is a better match for your call `auto res = std::max({b}, a);` than

```
template< class T >
constexpr const T& max( const T& a, const T& b );
```

which you are trying to call, since the `{b}` can be deduced to `std::initializer_list<int>` and that call has exact match conversion rank in both arguments, while the overload that you want to call requires a conversion from `int` to `double` which is not exact match.

The second argument is then considered the `Compare` functor to be called for the comparison operation, but calling a `double` fails obviously. The overload is not disabled if the second argument is not callable, which is why it is still chosen.

This doesn't happen with `auto res = std::max(a, {b});`, because there is no overload with `std::initializer_list` parameter for the second argument and so only the overload that you want to call is viable. The initializer list makes the second parameter a non-deduced context, which is why it works in contrast to `auto res = std::max(a, b);`, which fails due to template argument deduction mismatch between the two arguments.

Comment: wow, thank you for the precise explanation! I didn't expect that. Can I do anything to motivate the compiler to choose the desired template definition?

Comment: @CN85 Just use `auto res = std::max(a, {b});`. The order of arguments doesn't matter for your use case. `std::max` is not exactly symmetric in its arguments, but since you store the result to a new object, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

In your third 'experiment', you have an initializer list as the first argument to `std::max`; thus, the compiler is attempting to use the following template [(see cppreference)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max):

```cpp
template< class T, class Compare >
T max( std::initializer_list<T> ilist, Compare comp );
```

in which the second argument needs to be a comparison function.